# User tracking except cookies, sessions, IP

Tags: java, http, cookies, https, user-tracking

I faced interesting behavior when actively navigating over pages of http://avito.ru

So, I did navigating very actively, opening one page per each 2-3 seconds.
After 1 minute I saw blank screen (this is how their ban works, without any explanation, time for ban is about 20 min). 
I used LiveHeaders FF plugin to check response headers - and response was 403.

OK, I cleared cookies, restarted my FF, but still saw blank screen with response 403.
OK, I started Chrome, but still blank screen  (so, tracking method is not cookie/session)
OK, I took my laptop, but screen also blank there (ok, so may be I was banned by IP?)

BUT, surprisingly, I was able to download real source page from Java (using HttpClient library).

This is 100% reproducible, played whole day with it.

So, the question is : what tracking mechanism avito.ru uses ? I was thinking about : SSL cerificate header (they redirect to HTTPS pages), TCP headers..

Comment: There isn't anything trackable in the TCP header.  The source port value changes as TCP connections are closed and reopened.

Comment: Craig, thanks for your comment. It looks like FF (but Chrome not!) leaking my external IP even if I use anonymous proxy (or I misconfigured it somewhere). If you still interested in issue - here is a link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827967/anonymous-proxy-not-working-only-for-firefox-for-chrome-ok  Thanks again for your reply!